# Rename app data folder, Root

Tags: android, root

I have Root Access in my Android java app and I want to rename a folder located at `"/data/data/com.webi.west/"` rename to `"/com.webi.west2/"` in the same directory
how may I do this in android?
I have tried

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mv " + folderName + " " + "newFolderName");
```

no errors, But no success either
I'm using same process to execute this command which is `exec("su");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how I got it working,
I'm not using Java Runtime/Process now as that's not working for me...!

```
String dir = "data/data/com.example.app";
String tmp = "data/data/com.example.app2";

RootTools.isAccessGiven();
String commands[] = {"mv " + dir + " " + tmp);
Command comm = new Command(0, commands)
{
    @Override
    public void commandOutput(int p1, String p2)
    {
        // TODO implement
    }

    @Override
    public void commandTerminated(int p1, String p2)
    {
        toast(p2);
    }

    @Override
    public void commandCompleted(int p1, int p2)
    {
        toast("Success");
    }
};

try
{
    RootTools.getShell(true).add(comm);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    toast(CONVERT2STRING + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.webi.west"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

You just have to change value of the package into `com.webi.west2`Hope it helps you.

Comment: No, I'm not gonna change my own package code, actually I want to change another app's package folder, why? I can't tell why in public post/comment